# WildFly/JBoss Datasource definition for Derby fails

Tags: wildfly, datasource

I'm hoping this is just a stupid question, but after googling around and browsing the WildFly docs, I can't seem to link things up.

I have an EJB application which has been working since forever, but with JPA backed by the H2 database.  The entity database has grown so large that the H2 implementation now has extreme performance problems and I need to migrate to a Derby backstore.

The problem is that the H2 DS is sort of "baked into" WF as ExampleDS, but Derby is not, and I can't seem to get Derby defined as a datasource.  My first try was to define it with a module.xml, but I wasn't having much luck, so as I don't need domain, I opted to just drop derbyclient.jar into standalone/deployments, which seemed to work fine.

With the client JAR deployed, my attempt to define the DVDDerbyDS datasource gets this:

```
[jboss@ftgme2 ~/wildfly-23.0.0.Final/bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c     
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=DVDDerbyDS:add(
\
>     jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/DVDDerbyDS,\
>     driver-name=derbyclient,\
>     connection-url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DVD\
> )
{
   "outcome" => "failed",
   "failure-description" => {
       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc
-driver.derbyclient"],
       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
           "org.wildfly.data-source.DVDDerbyDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.de
rbyclient]",
           "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/DVDDerbyDS is missing  
[jboss.jdbc-driver.derbyclient]"
       ]                                                                        
   },                                                                           
   "rolled-back" => true                                                        
}
```

I'm guessing that this is a simple case of two operands that need to match not matching, probably the derbyclient info.  But deploying derbyclient gives no hint of how to reference it, and every permutation I've tried has failed.

Any ideas ?

In the management console deployments, derbyclient.jar appears as deployed and enabled and is referred to only as derbyclient.jar. Modifying the CLI above still fails: –

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=DVDDerbyDS:add( jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/DVDDerbyDS, driver-name=derbyclient.jar, connection-url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DVD) –

{ "outcome" => "failed", "failure-description" => { "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc -driver.derbyclient_jar"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [ "org.wildfly.data-source.DVDDerbyDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.de rbyclient_jar]", "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/DVDDerbyDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.derbyclient_jar]" ] }, "rolled-back" => true } –

The same using derbyclient_jar. –

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
    "driver-name" => "h2",
    "deployment-name" => undefined,
    "driver-module-name" => "com.h2database.h2",
    "module-slot" => "main",
    "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
    "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" =>   "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
    "datasource-class-info" => [{"org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"     => { 
        "URL" => "java.lang.String",
        "description" => "java.lang.String",
        "loginTimeout" => "int",
        "password" => "java.lang.String",
        "url" => "java.lang.String",
        "user" => "java.lang.String"
    }}],
    "driver-class-name" => "org.h2.Driver",
    "driver-major-version" => 1,
    "driver-minor-version" => 4,
    "jdbc-compliant" => true
}]
```

}

[standalone@localhost:9990 /]

but

```
[jboss@ftgme2 ~/wildfly-23.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments]$ cat derbyclient.jar.deployed
derbyclient.jar

[standalone@localhost:9990 /]   /deployment=derbyclient.jar:browse-content(path=META-INF/services/)
   {
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
    "path" => "java.sql.Driver",
    "directory" => false,
    "file-size" => 47L
   }]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but the RedHat JIRA now redirects to you and you need to realize that your comment paradigm is quite different from theirs.

Comment: How did you install the derby driver? What JIRA are you referring to as well?

Comment: I just copied it to standalone/deployments.  The deployment gave no errors.

Comment: What does the following CLI command show? `/subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list/

Comment: See above edited report.

Comment: Is it a compliant data source driver JAR?  Does `/deployment=derbyclient.jar:browse-content(path=META-INF/services/)` return a `java.sql.Driver` file?

Comment: See above edited report.

Comment: For some reason it's not seeing it as a JDBC driver. What specific version of the Derby driver you are you attempting to use?

Comment: 10.15.2.0 .......

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `derbyclient.jar` does not contain everything you need. It worked for me with the following.

First you need to install the driver as a module:

```
# Set the path to Derby and add a module for the driver
set DERBY_HOME=/path/to/db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin
module add --name=org.apache.derby --resources=$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyclient.jar,$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar,$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyshared.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api --resource-delimiter=,

# Add the JDBC driver
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=derby:add(driver-module-name=org.apache.derby, driver-name=derby, driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver)
```

Then you can add your data source:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=DVDDerbyDS:add(jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/DVDDerbyDS, driver-name=derby, connection-url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DVD)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort; that worked a charm.  Could you point me to the documentation you referenced to get those commands ?

Comment: TBH that was mostly from memory. However, take a look at https://docs.wildfly.org.